# Array dimension keeps increasing in debug mode

Tags: google-apps-script, rhino, google-apps-script-editor

When I use GAS debug mode, the script sometimes pauses where there are no break points and every time I click the play button, some arrays shown in the debug panel increase their dimensions like the image below. Is this a GAS's bug or is my code doing something bad?

[image]

Comment: I noticed this behavior too recently, but expanding didn't actually yield arrays like this. I think it's a benign bug.

Comment: Related issue https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6371

Comment: I think it's a bug when there is a bug in the code :) Would be better if the debugger threw an error.